# What is the maximum safe voltage for 1.5V and 3.7V gadgets of consumer electronics?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries

I know that most electronics for 1xAA battery accept at least 1.1-2V and for li-ion 3.5-4.3V. But what is probable safe maximum? Can I use li-ion with 20ohm resistor or even without it for supply 1xAA gadget or 5V for li-ion without noisy DC-DC converters?
Possible easy solution is for example use LED/zener 2V, lm317, some IC current limiters but maybe it is redundant and internal gadgets PSU have it and do it more efficient way due impulse power use of circuits?

Comment: Do you have a specific device or board you are trying to power? If so, check the data sheet or manual for it.

Comment: And where I can find datasheet for noname camcorder, brand mp3-player or everything else? The question is about hacking and experience. The question is not about batteries parameters.

Comment: To power a lower voltage circuit with higher voltage battery, you absolutely need a voltage regulator. (granted your battery is able to supply enough power for both regulator and load)

If you want to go absolutely cheap, you should consider zener based regulator. It takes just one zener diode and one resistor.

Answer (score 2):

The "probable safe maximum" is the absolute maximum value specified on the data sheet for the component.

Answer (score -1):

You could assume the circuit has been competently designed and look at the data sheets for various batteries to see what the maximum voltage output is. Generally cheap batteries have somewhat sparse data so you may have to look further for something like temperature coefficient of output voltage. For example, if the cell is an alkaline AA, [here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Batteries%20PDFS/LR03EGA_Br.pdf) is a Panasonic data sheet.

[image]

So, it appears around 1.5 ~ 1.6V is reasonable for a maximum initial voltage.

[Here](http://www.drkfs.net/coldbattery.htm) is someone who has done low-temperature testing of various batteries, and found that (from room temperature down) Alkaline cells are fairly stable in voltage.

[image]

A good place to look for battery datasheets is the online sites of distributors such as digikey.com and mouser.com, which will link back to the original manufacturer data sheets. You can also search the manufacturer data sheets for application manuals.